# "No Operation named [input] in the Graph" when using in a java programm a model from hub.KerasLayer with python and tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: java, python, tensorflow

I trained a mobilnet_v2 tensorflow model using tf 2.1.0 and hub.KerasLayer with python and exported it in pb format with tf.keras.models.save_model.
I loaded it with java but I can't find a way to properly feed the graph.

Here is the model building and exporting code :

```
for image_batch, label_batch in train_generator:
    break

IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/2"

feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url,
                                         input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                         name='input')

feature_batch = feature_extractor_layer(image_batch)
feature_extractor_layer.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor_layer,
  layers.Dense(train_generator.num_classes, name='output')
])

...... training .......

tf.keras.models.save_model(model,export_path)
```

Here is the way I try to feed it in java :

```
Tensor inputImage = getTensorFromImage() // a method defined in other code and tested ok
final Session s = new Session(graphFromPBLoadedModel);
final Tensor result = s.runner().feed("input", inputImage )
                        .fetch("output").run().get(0))
```

Here is the generated exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Operation named [input] in the Graph
```

I assume it's a signature problem during build or export but don't find the right way to do it...

Comment: Your saving it as a `tf.keras` model, have you tried saving as `SavedModel` (`tf.saved_model.save(model, "./dir")`)?

Comment: Thank you @FrederikBode but the `tf.keras.models.save_model()` already export in `SavedModel` format by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see where the problem was coming from running `saved_model_cli show --dir '.' --all` in my exported model directory :

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input_input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 224, 224, 3)
        name: serving_default_input_input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['output'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 5)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Using `"serving_default_input_input"`, I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks@toupieBleue 's answer,I directed to my exported model directory and run the commond-line: `saved_model_cli show --dir '.' --all`,some information listed as follow:

```
    (base) pro@prodeMacBook-Pro my_model % saved_model_cli show --dir '.' --all

MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is: 

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['lstm_input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 7, 6)
        name: serving_default_lstm_input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['dense_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Using `serving_default_lstm_input:0`, I could solve the problem.