# "No Operation named [input] in the Graph" in Java

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

Following [this Colab exeercise](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/multi-class-neural-networks/programming-exercise) from Google's ML Crash Course, I generated a model in Python for the MNIST database. The code looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


def create_model(my_learning_rate):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28), name='input'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax', name='output'))
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=my_learning_rate),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


def train_model(model, train_features, train_label, epochs,
                batch_size=None, validation_split=0.1):
    history = model.fit(x=train_features, y=train_label, batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs, shuffle=True,
                        validation_split=validation_split)
    epochs = history.epoch
    hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
    return epochs, hist


if __name__ == '__main__':
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    x_train_normalized = x_train / 255.0
    x_test_normalized = x_test / 255.0

    learning_rate = 0.003
    epochs = 50
    batch_size = 4000
    validation_split = 0.2

    my_model = create_model(learning_rate)
    epochs, hist = train_model(my_model, x_train_normalized, y_train,
                               epochs, batch_size, validation_split)

    my_model.save('my_model')
```

The model is saved to the "my_model" folder, as it should. Now I load it again in my Java program:

```
public class HelloTensorFlow {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String filePath = Paths.get("my_model").toAbsolutePath().toString();
        try (final SavedModelBundle b = SavedModelBundle.load(filePath, "serve")) {
            final Session sess = b.session();

            final Tensor<Float> x = Tensor.create(new float[1][28 * 28], Float.class);
            final List<Tensor<?>> run = sess.runner()
                    .feed("input", x)
                    .fetch("output")
                    .run();

            final float[] y = run.get(0).copyTo(new float[1]);
            System.out.println(y[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

The model is loaded but the runner does not work. When I execute the program, I get "No Operation named [input] in the Graph", even though my Input has this name. What am I doing wrong. I have the newest TensorFlow versions: 2.3.0 (Python) and 1.15.0 (Java).

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632574/no-operation-named-input-in-the-graph-when-using-in-a-java-programm-a-model/71908916#71908916.) I solved my same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. TensorFlow 2 seems to have odd naming schemes, but using the MetaGraphDef, this can be deciphered. First, you need the [org.tensorflow.proto](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow/proto) dependency. Then, you can extract the information from the meta graph like so:

```
final MetaGraphDef metaGraphDef = MetaGraphDef.parseFrom(bundle.metaGraphDef());
final SignatureDef signatureDef = metaGraphDef.getSignatureDefMap().get("serving_default");

final TensorInfo inputTensorInfo = signatureDef.getInputsMap()
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> ...);

final TensorInfo outputTensorInfo = signatureDef.getOutputsMap()
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> ...);
```

Now you can feed the tensor you created into the name from `inputTensorInfo.getName()` and fetch the results from `outputTensorInfo.getName()`.

Comment: Because some of the functions you used there are now deprecated, you have to now do this instead:

` MetaGraphDef metaGraphDef = model.metaGraphDef();
        Map<String, SignatureDef> signatureMapDef = metaGraphDef.getSignatureDefMap();
        System.out.println("Signature map def:" + signatureMapDef);`